# Aggregate values by date

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Results
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public decimal Result {get; set;}
}
public class Sums
{
    public decimal YearlySum {get; set;}
    public decimal MonthlySum {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}
```

I have a collection of Results object.

I want to populate Sums list with Yearly, Monthly sums based on date.

YearlySum is the sum of all Results' values in the provided date's year (until the provided date), and MonthlySum is the sum of Results' values in the provided date's month (until the provided date)

How to do it using Linq?

Comment: Maybe you should try to do it *without* linq first. Then it´s easy to translate it.This helps you understand, what a linq-statement actually does and how to write efficient code. Anyway why do you have an aggregation-class at all? What should its properties equal to for jan, feb, march, ...? Makes not much sense to me.

Comment: what do you exactly want to be stored in YearlySum and MonthlySum?

Comment: The sum of "Result" Value of all dates in current year till current date - YearlySum. The sume of "Result" Value of all dates in current month till current date - Monthly Sum

Comment: Can you share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where your populate the data and your attempts to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this function should do the work :

```
public Sum GetSumFromResultsAndDate(IEnumerable<Results> results, DateTime date) {
    return new Sum {
        Date = date,
        MonthlySum = results
            .Where(r => r.Date.Year == date.Year && r.Date.Month == date.Month && r.Date <= date)
            .Sum(r => r.Value) ,
        YearlySum = results
            .Where(r => r.Date.Year == date.Year && r.Date <= date)
            .Sum(r => r.Value)
    }
}
```

(make the sum of all Result which have the same month and year than provided date for monthly sum, and sum of all results which have the same year as the provided date for the yearly sum)

EDIT : added the "result date inferior to provided date" condition as per question clarification

Comment: You can write it `... GetSumFromResultsAndDate(IEnumerable<Results> results, DateTime date) => new Sum {...`

Comment: @aloisdg  Thanks for the tip. I'm wondering, does that make any difference ? Is that considered better practice ?

Comment: It is just cleaner. The result is the same like all syntactic sugar.